# Time.zone setting in controller only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Rails app where I set the timezone for each request in a before action in my controller like so:

```
Time.zone="Central Time (US & Canada")
```

I can print the time zone with

```
puts Time.zone
```

and this is what is printed out.

```
(GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
```

All of this works fine until I call a method in my model. When I do, the timezone is lost and I have to set `Time.zone` again in my model.

From my controller if I call the method below that's in my model it prints UTC time.

Model

```
def self.import_file(file)
    puts Time.zone
    # this prints out UTC time. 
end
```

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

Comment: When you say you're setting the time zone in the controller, does this vary depend on who's logged in? Or is that supposed to be a global configuration for the whole rails application? In the case of the former, you'd need to pass the time zone into the model method as a parameter; models have no knowledge of the "current user". In the case of the latter, then this code never belonged in the controller in the first place! You should set the global time zone in `config/application.rb`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Time.zone` is set as a thread variable. If you're in a different thread (i.e. a background worker, process, irb), `Time.zone` will be your application's default (usually set in `config/application.rb`).

If you're not in a different thread/process, make sure you're not accidentally calling `Time.zone = nil`. You should also check out the Rails definitive `Time.use_zone` example at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-use_zone.